# firebase push notification error spring boot server side

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

iam trying to send a notification from spring boot server side to client side android ..
the server is working great and all things is good

```
2020-09-01 08:13:07.691  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-09-01 08:13:07.691  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-09-01 08:13:08.658  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-01 08:13:08.668  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-01 08:13:08.669  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-09-01 08:13:08.772  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-01 08:13:08.772  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1081 ms
2020-09-01 08:13:08.904  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.s.S.service.FCMInitializer           : Firebase application has been initialized
2020-09-01 08:13:09.015  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-01 08:13:09.159  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-09-01 08:13:09.175  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-09-01 08:13:09.207  INFO 18941 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

when i trying to send a notification i get that error :

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Error while calling FCM backend service
```

so this is my server code :

class FCMInitializer :

```
@Service
```

public class FCMInitializer {

```
@Value("${app.firebase-configuration-file}")
private String firebaseConfigPath;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FCMInitializer.class);

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    try {
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource(firebaseConfigPath).getInputStream())).build();
        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            logger.info("Firebase application has been initialized");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

class FCMService

```
public class FCMService {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FCMService.class);

public void sendMessage(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithData(data, request);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(message);
    String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
    logger.info("Sent message with data. Topic: " + request.getTopic() + ", " + response+ " msg "+jsonOutput);
}

public void sendMessageCustomDataWithTopic(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithDataCustomWithTopic(data, request);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(message);
    String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
    logger.info("Sent message with data. Topic: " + data.get("topic") + ", " + response+ " msg "+jsonOutput);
}


public void sendMessageWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithoutData(request);
    String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
    logger.info("Sent message without data. Topic: " + request.getTopic() + ", " + response);
}

public void sendMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(request);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(message);
    String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
    logger.info("Sent message to token. Device token: " + request.getToken() + ", " + response+ " msg "+jsonOutput);
}

private String sendAndGetResponse(Message message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
}

private AndroidConfig getAndroidConfig(String topic) {
    return AndroidConfig.builder()
            .setTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(2).toMillis()).setCollapseKey(topic)
            .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
            .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setSound(NotificationParameter.SOUND.getValue())
                    .setColor(NotificationParameter.COLOR.getValue()).setTag(topic).build()).build();
}

private ApnsConfig getApnsConfig(String topic) {
    return ApnsConfig.builder()
            .setAps(Aps.builder().setCategory(topic).setThreadId(topic).build()).build();
}

private Message getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request) {
    return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).setToken(request.getToken())
            .build();
}

private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request) {
    return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).setTopic(request.getTopic())
            .build();
}

private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithData(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request) {
    return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).putAllData(data).setToken(request.getToken())
            .build();
}

private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(PushNotificationRequest request) {
    AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig(request.getTopic());
    ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig(request.getTopic());
    return Message.builder()
            .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig).setNotification(
                    new Notification(request.getTitle(), request.getMessage()));
}


private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithDataCustomWithTopic(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request) {
    return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilderCustomDataWithTopic(data, request).putAllData(data).setTopic(request.getTopic())
            .build();
}

private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilderCustomDataWithTopic(Map<String, String> data, PushNotificationRequest request) {
    AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig(request.getTopic());
    ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig(data.get(request.getTopic()));
    return Message.builder()
            .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig).setNotification(
                    new Notification(data.get("title"), data.toString()));
}
```

this is pushnotification class :

```
  @Service
public class PushNotificationService {

    // @Value("#{${app.notifications.defaults}}")
    //private Map<String, String> defaults;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PushNotificationService.class);
    private FCMService fcmService;

    public PushNotificationService(FCMService fcmService) {
        this.fcmService = fcmService;
    }


    public void sendPushNotification(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessage(getSamplePayloadData(), request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendPushNotificationCustomDataWithTopic(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageCustomDataWithTopic(getSamplePayloadDataCustom(), request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendPushNotificationCustomDataWithTopicWithSpecificJson(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageCustomDataWithTopic(getSamplePayloadDataWithSpecificJsonFormat(), request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendPushNotificationWithoutData(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageWithoutData(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void sendPushNotificationToToken(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        try {
            fcmService.sendMessageToToken(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private Map<String, String> getSamplePayloadData() {
        Map<String, String> pushData = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> article_data = new HashMap<>();

        pushData.put("title", "Notification for pending work");
        pushData.put("message", "pls complete your pending task immediately");
        pushData.put("image", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firoz-Hasan/SpringBootPushNotification/master/pushnotificationconcept.png");
        pushData.put("timestamp", "2020-07-11 19:23:21");
        pushData.put("article_data", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
       // pushData.put("article_data","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
       // payload.put("article_data", String.valueOf(article_data));
       // pushData.put("payload", String.valueOf(payload));

     //   data.put("data", String.valueOf(pushData));
        return pushData;
    }


    private Map<String, String> getSamplePayloadDataCustom() {
        Map<String, String> pushData = new HashMap<>();
        pushData.put("title", "Notification for pending work-custom");
        pushData.put("message", "pls complete your pending task immediately-custom");
        pushData.put("image", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firoz-Hasan/SpringBootPushNotification/master/pushnotificationconcept.png");
        pushData.put("timestamp", String.valueOf(new Date()));
        pushData.put("article_data", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
       // pushData.put("article_data","vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
        return pushData;
    }


    private Map<String, String> getSamplePayloadDataWithSpecificJsonFormat() {
        Map<String, String> pushData = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
       ArrayList<Map<String, String>> payload = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> article_data = new HashMap<>();

        pushData.put("title", "jsonformat");
        pushData.put("message", "itsworkingkudussssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
        pushData.put("image", "qqq");
        pushData.put("timestamp", "fefe");
        article_data.put("article_data", "ffff");
        payload.add(article_data);
        pushData.put("payload", String.valueOf(payload));
        data.put("data", String.valueOf(pushData));
        return data;

        /*getPreconfiguredMessageBuilderCustomDataWithTopic will get some issue to generate notification as
        * data.get("title") wont give us title as its mapped inside data
        * */
    }
```

and this is controller :

```
@RestController
public class PushNotificationController {

    private PushNotificationService pushNotificationService;

    public PushNotificationController(PushNotificationService pushNotificationService) {
        this.pushNotificationService = pushNotificationService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/topic")
    public ResponseEntity sendNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationWithoutData(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/token")
    public ResponseEntity sendTokenNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationToToken(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/data")
    public ResponseEntity sendDataNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotification(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/notification/data/customdatawithtopic")
    public ResponseEntity sendDataNotificationCustom(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationCustomDataWithTopic(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping("/notification/data/customdatawithtopicjson")
    public ResponseEntity sendDataNotificationCustomWithSpecificJson(@RequestBody PushNotificationRequest request) {
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationCustomDataWithTopicWithSpecificJson(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new PushNotificationResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Notification has been sent."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public void sendAutomaticNotification(){
        PushNotificationRequest request = new PushNotificationRequest();
        request.setTopic("global");
        pushNotificationService.sendPushNotificationCustomDataWithTopicWithSpecificJson(request);
    }
}
```

when i want to send a request via postman reponse is 200 so its good

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Notification has been sent."
}
```

but in the debugger console i get that error and the server keep running over and over when i post request , so all the problem is here :

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Error while calling FCM backend
```

so can you help me guys please !

Comment: are you able to make other requests to Firebase? Seems to be an error with the authentication... let me know.

Comment: Yes , when i send notification from firebase console its work with same token i using in the server

Comment: Can you add the final request object that you are passing to firebase ?

Comment: Iam using postman to send the request {
   "title":"Notification for pending work",
    "message":"pls complete your pending task immediately",
   "token":"f7uw_r_WaHk:APA91bHuOc-aqwey05vzDe4Z53S51EBYbgYDJAmB_iRhRIqHAvZNMM7YcbCs76A6gt_xPHPXKVMV9dvuY40p8_FDIKsa6y0VcpoigsmdREXNCK1wi4ZcqBP2YAYslaiLRv59xQFBi9PC"
 }