# i want to make realtime changing data On RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, real-time, android-adapter

I'am trying to make refresh every 1 sec in my RecyclerView but i don't know how can i do it iam using my API , when something changed in my api i want to make that change in my RecylerView whitout the swiper or i want to make the swiper swipe every 1 sec .. so this is my Code :

```
public class InformationNow extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refresh;
    private ArrayList<TrashCanModel> trashCanModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private  InformationNowAdapter informationNowAdapter ;
    private String url = "http://192.168.1.34:9090/TrashCanData/lastrow";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_now);
        refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.Swiper);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Now);

        dialog = new Dialog(this);


        refresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        refresh.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                trashCanModels.clear();
                getData();
            }
        });


    }

    private void getData() {
        refresh.setRefreshing(true);

        arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        //JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        TrashCanModel cat = new TrashCanModel();
                        cat.setDistance(jsonObject.getInt("distance"));
                        cat.setTemperature(jsonObject.getInt("temperature"));
                        cat.setHumidity(jsonObject.getInt("humidity"));
                        Log.e("*********", cat.getDistance().toString());
                        Log.e("*********", cat.getTemperature().toString());
                        Log.e("*********", cat.getHumidity().toString());

                        trashCanModels.add(cat);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
                adapterPush(trashCanModels);
                refresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(InformationNow.this);
        requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    }

    private void adapterPush(ArrayList<TrashCanModel> trashCanModels) {

        informationNowAdapter = new InformationNowAdapter(this, trashCanModels);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(informationNowAdapter);

    }
 
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        trashCanModels.clear();
        getData();

    }

}
```

and my adapter :

```
public class InformationNowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InformationNowAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    private Context context ;
    private ArrayList<TrashCanModel> trashCanModels;
    private String url = "";
//


    public InformationNowAdapter (Context context , ArrayList<TrashCanModel> trashCanModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.trashCanModels=trashCanModels;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InformationNowAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view ;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trashcan_list , parent , false);
        return new InformationNowAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InformationNowAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //holder.id.setText("#"+String.valueOf(position+1));
        holder.distance.setText(trashCanModels.get(position).getDistance().toString());
        holder.temperature.setText(trashCanModels.get(position).getTemperature().toString());
        holder.humidity.setText(trashCanModels.get(position).getHumidity().toString());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trashCanModels.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView  distance , temperature , humidity ;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            temperature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
            humidity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.humidity);
//
        }
    }

}
```

so how can i make refresh data every 1 sec !

Comment: How many of those every-second requests will your backend be able to handle? How much data do you rhink are the clients spending on those requests and what a bandwidth will your backend need for those requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Timer to do that

```
Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                trashCanModels.clear();
                getData();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

call `repeatTask.cancel()` when you want to stop
But I think you should use push notification when your api change or use firebase or socket.io instead

Comment: Where can i put this function?? Iam not using firebase .. spring boot

Comment: you can put it inside onCreate

Comment: Ok thanks , i like you idea about socket io, can you show me a little bit how can i make my api realtime with it ?

Comment: use socket require you rebuild your server. easier way is when your data is changed you can use FCM to notify android reload api

Comment: Can you ckeck this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693405/firebase-push-notification-error-spring-boot-server-side

Comment: Sorry IDK spring boot